# How to avoid fetching the source jar from a flatDir dependency with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle build script, with mixed Maven dependencies (I use Maven Central for dependencies resolution) and a local directory. The snippet is this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    flatDir name: 'directoryRepository', dirs: 'tools/libs'
}
```

Then I need to declare my local dependencies this way:

```
dependencies {
    compile ":commons-cli:1.0@jar"
}
```

I cannot use the files('...') notation (because other parts of the script would fail with a class cast exception from Array to HashMap, and I cannot change that part).

The jar files are added to the build path correctly. The problem is that Gradle wants to fetch, for every jar in the 'tools/libs', another '-source' jar.
Indeed, if I have in the tools/libs folder:

```
commons-cli-1.0.jar
commons-cli-1.0-sources.jar
```

all works fine. If I remove the source jar, it gives the error "unable to resolve dependency", poiting out the -source jar.

I have more then 50 files to be managed this way, and of course I haven't the source jars (nor I'm interested to have).

How can I exclude the source jar fetching?

Many thanks in advance for any hints.

Fabio Da Soghe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using IDEA there's a module-wide setting `ideaModule.downloadSources = false` which can help, but it will disable all source downloading for IDEA.

Not sure what you meant by `files(...)` notation, but how about trying this?:

```
dependencies{
  ...
  compile fileTree( dir: "toos/lib", include: '*.jar' )
  ... or ...
  compile fileTree( dir: "toos/lib", includes: ['*.jar'] )
}
```

**Edit:**

There appears to be an associated [bug report](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1621), fixed in milestone 5. Giving it a try revealed that the error is still there but now it's just a warning and the build will succeed. Apparently the warning is coming from Ivy so there is no easy fix for it :(

Comment: By files(...) I meant what you wrote: I cannot use files(...) nor fileTree(...) because that creates an array that arises a ClassCastException in subsequent code. And I cannot change it.
Anyway, I'm using Eclipse. Your hint suggests me to search into the Eclpse plugin, although it sounds weird to me: why Gradle should bother with the IDE I'm using? The concept of source downloading should be indipendent from the particular IDE used, no?

Comment: Found the equivalent for the Eclipse plugin: `eclipseClasspath.downloadSources = false` Accepting your answer for having pointed me to the right direction (I was searching a dependency-level settings, which seems to not exists).

Comment: You are right about the source downloading. I guess I'll have a deeper look into this, there must be a better solution.

Comment: It would be great :o) I really have searched a lot and found anything, but I have to say I'm a bit dumb with Groovy...